# if/elif not working as expected in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code

```
print "Choose a category: Animals, Jobs or Cars?"
while True:
    cat = str(raw_input())
    if cat.lower() == "animals":
        wordfile = open("Animals.txt")
        break
    elif cat.lower == "jobs":
        wordfile = open("Jobs.txt")
        break
    elif cat.lower == "cars":
        wordfile = open("Cars.txt")
        break
    else:
        print "That's not a valid category!"

wordlist = [line.split("\n") for line in wordfile]
print wordlist
```

When I enter animals, it works perfectly and prints the contents of my file. However when I enter jobs or cars, it tells me that that's not a valid category (it skips the elif's and goes straight to else) and I can't figure out why.

Comment: You're missing the parenthesis on `cat.lower` in your `elif` statements

Comment: Also, why using`cat = str(raw_input())` ? `raw_input()` itself will return a string.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you need to use `cat.lower()` in **all** cases:

```
print "Choose a category: Animals, Jobs or Cars?"
while True:
    cat = str(raw_input())
    if cat.lower() == "animals":
        wordfile = open("Animals.txt")
        break
    elif cat.lower() == "jobs":
        wordfile = open("Jobs.txt")
        break
    elif cat.lower() == "cars":
        wordfile = open("Cars.txt")
        break
    else:
        print "That's not a valid category!"

wordlist = [line.split("\n") for line in wordfile]
print wordlist
```

Using `cat.lower` will not actually execute the lowercase function, it will instead give you a reference to the actual function itself which messes up the if/elif statements

Answer (score 1):

Your missing `()` in the second and third `elif`s. Comparing a function to a string will yield False.

Comment: really this question need an answer ?

Comment: I'm not judgmental, but you may have a point. Also, someone seems to be upvoting stuff indiscriminately.